# custom serialization data on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my first post. I have a problem with my Laravel application. 
I need to modify the serialization of the data for my endpoint to get the data of a specific bike.
The endpoint return this:

```
{"bike":{"id":32,
         "unlock_code":2342,
         "rack": {"id":3,
                  "available_stands":10,
                  "latitude":"46.754",
                  "longitude":"8.5732",
                  "available_bikes":10
                },
        "bike_state":{"description":"Available"}
        }
}
```

but i want to have this:

```
{"bike":{"id":32,
         "unlock_code":2342,
        "rack":{"id":3,
                "available_stands":10,
                "latitude":"46.754",
                "longitude":"8.5732",
                "available_bikes":10
                },
        "bike_state":{"Available"}
        }
}
```

the field name ('description') must be hidden. It's the first time i use laravel and i don't know if it's possible to do this.

This is the model

```
class BikeState extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['id'];

    public function bikes() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bike');
    }
}
```

this is the repository with the method to retrieve the data:

```
class BikeRepository 
{
    public function findBikeById($id)
    {
    return Bike::with('rack','bikeState')->findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```

and this is the controller

```
class BikeController extends Controller
{
     private $bikeRepository;

     public function __construct(BikeRepository $bikeRepository)
     {
          $this->bikeRepository = $bikeRepository;
     }

     public function getBike($id)  
     {
          return response() ->json(['bike' => $this -> bikeRepository -> 
          findBikeByid($id)], 200);
     }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: **You cant** As what you want is invalid JSON

Comment: please full code

Comment: @SergeyB. i added the code

Answer (score 0):

Create an accessor on your **Bike** model like this:

```
public function getBikeStateAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_encode($this->attributes['description']);
    }
```

Then add accessor to **Bike** model's array like this:

```
protected $appends = ['bike_state'];
```